#  the code of JavaScript files in the master page not running in web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

In Web Application Solution, I have a master page that is located in the root folder. I also have web forms that use this master page and are located in a folder in the root folder.

master page ----located----> root folder

web forms--------located----> root folder/forms

I have JavaScript that cannot run in the web form because this code can't access the source file in the scripts folder.
I used the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/stmenu.js") %>"></script>
```

However, it results in this error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

How can I insert the JavaScript, that is located in a separate folder, into the master page?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `runat="server"` to the head tag like this

```
<head runat="server">
```

Also please use `Page.ResolveUrl` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/stmenu.js") %>">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another asp:contentplaceholder in the <head> section of the Master Page where the Webforms can place their Javascript references and code.